# How to make a hidden (ng-cloaked) item preserve the space it takes up when its visible

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

In a table... I have action buttons that appear when the mouse goes over that row by using ng-cloak and ng-show.

**The problem is**, when the icon appears, it takes up more space than when its not there, and the html around it jumps.

[image: example of problem in action]

I even set my css to use display:none for ng-click, which I thought is supposed to preserve the space the hidden element takes up (as opposed to visibility: hidden).

**How can I fix this? OR can you think of a better way to do this?**

```
     <tr id="treeHistoryItem" ng-repeat="o in tree.history" 
             ng-mouseover="showEdit=true" ng-mouseleave="showEdit=false">

          ....

         <td align='right'>
            <a ng:cloak ng-show="showEdit" href 
              ng-click="removeTreeRec(o.$$hashKey)" 
               class='fa fa-times _red _size6' ></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Here's a plunkr example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/POA9b2pZA9QbBgcMsxBE?p=preview

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) is used to

> prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the
>   browser in its raw (uncompiled) form **while your application is
>   loading**

The correct place to put it would be way further up in the DOM tree but it's really meant to solve a different problem than this. I would try just going with `ngShow` here and rather override its CSS class, `.ng-hide` to do `visibility: hidden;` rather than `display: none;`

(Visibility is the one that preserves space, not display).

As noted in the [docs for ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) you will need to use `!important` to override the `display: none;` property.

Note, in the version of Angular you were using in your plunker, `ngShow` is adding an inline style to the hidden element. I am not sure which version moved away from that but I could not get this approach to work with 1.0.5.

Here's it working with your plunker, but with the most recent Angular version:
[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/zCKBB5pbKrT00vEPh8Ci?p=preview)

Comment: i tried this:  <a ngHide ng-show="showEdit" href ... and it still jumps.  i tried this: <a class='ng-hide' ... and it stays hidden.. the ng-show wont override the "visibility:hidden"

Comment: Right, there's a few problems there. `vidibility` is a spelling mistake, and as the docs which I forgot to link you to state, `!important` must be used to override the `.ng-hide` class correctly. Last you were using a very old version of angular. I'll update my answer. Here's a plunker of it working, but with 1.2.17 of  angular. http://plnkr.co/edit/zCKBB5pbKrT00vEPh8Ci?p=preview

Comment: Afraid I can't get this to work with the version you were using. I did not expect to see 1.0.5 still in use. I would encourage you to migrate to the 1.2.x branch though you might expect having to deal with some API changes if your codebase is big.

Comment: @ivami - i just grabbed whatever angular version came up on google for "plunkr angular" ... thanks for fixing this!

Comment: In my case I ended up editing line 28364 of angular.js and changed ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate){display:none !important;} for .ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate){display: block!important;visibility:hidden;}. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 6):

Late to the party, however...

In my case, whenever I need to do this i use ng-class. If you copy the code from your ng-show and put it into:
HTML:

```
ng-class="{'disabled': showEdit}"
ng-click="showEdit && removeTreeRec(o.$$hashKey)"
```

CSS:

```
.disabled {
 visibility: hidden;
 cursor: default;
}
```

Cursor:default simply makes the cursor not change for usability purposes.
Hope this helps!

EDIT: in this case adding the cursor and showEdit to the ng-click probably wont make a difference as the icon will always be shown if the mouse is over the icon due to the hover event, but nonetheless I think it's good practice to cover all bases

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using css. You can put to your `<tr>` a height.

Comment: yes, but im trying to stay away from that... since the height will change sometimes... i supposed i could do a min-height though.

Answer (score 1):

you can assign height to your containers which sometimes isn't practical because you don't always know the content height up front. or you could change your classes content declaring them to be

```
   .not_remove.ng-cloak,.not_remove.ng-hide{
          display:block;
          visibility:hidden;

   }
```

note the .not_remove class. this will enforce this new behavior only on elements who have the no_remove class. the display property can be setted to what ever flow your element follows

Comment: your problem is that you are using angular 1.0.5 in your example in older versions angular enforced display:none through inline styling which takes precedence over any other rule. in later versions they switch to class based styling. you should update angular anyways so i suggest you to do that