# Use ng-hide but save empty space

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I want to hide my element by ng-hide but I want to save empty space in my DOM. In other words, I want to empty one element not hide an element.

How can I do this using ng-hide, or using any other angular feature?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to remove the element from the dom? Or do you mean that you want a blank zone to appear in the page. If the former, use ng-if. If the latter, use CSS.

Comment: I want a black zone instead of data in some element. I would prefer to use angular instead of CSS.

Comment: Use ng-if or ng-hide to remove the data from the zone. Use CSS to make sure the zone has a black background and a minimum width/height. angular doesn't deal with visual style. That's what CSS is for.

Comment: Is it possible to create custom directive for doing this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383299/how-to-make-a-hidden-ng-cloaked-item-preserve-the-space-it-takes-up-when-its-v/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-if` or `ng-when` for the same. It will remove element from DOM if condition is not satisfied.